# Set background image for my Titanium view

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How do I set my background image for my view as for example http://bluebackground.com/__oneclick_uploads/2008/04/blue_background_03.jpg ?

I knew how to do it from local folder something like backgroundImage:'images/bg.png',
but how do I fetch using http and set it as my background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set image like :

```
view.backgroundImage="http://bluebackground.com/__oneclick_uploads/2008/04/blue_background_03.jpg";
```

This will take some time in downloading image and set it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks.. But when I get the http url from a json and use it, It tries to look at Resources folder.. var data = {"url":"http://xyz.com/bg.jpg"}  view.backgroundImage = data.url; If I do this, I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resources/ http://xyz.com/bg.jpg ... How do I solve this? Thanks for help!

Comment: data.url is already in the form of "http:// xyz.com/bg.jpg" ? My json will have url in along with http:// Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried my code for any static url? not from your json.I think your server have that urls but not image data.

Answer (score 1):

Pls Try this set image on top corner...

var bgImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 height  : 'auto',
 width   : 'auto',
 top     : 0,
 left    : 0,
 image   : 'images/h-5.jpg'
});
win.add(bgImage);

Answer (score 0):

If the image is on the web you may want to simply try creating a full sized image view with the URL and a low zIndex and adding it to your window.